# Unable to get files in directory outside codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get all the files in a folder outside CodeIgniter scope but I get nothing.
The file with the script is inside the application/views/user
I tried:

```
$dirname = site_url()."images/users/";
//echo $dirname;
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<div class="img_container" style="float:left;border:1px solid red;width:160px;height:140px;">
              <img src="'.$image.'" width="160" height="140" alt="Media"/><br />
          </div>
    </div>';
}
```

also tried:

```
$dir = site_url()."images/users/";
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
```

none of them work.

Any help please.

Comment: What does `site_url()` output?

Comment: you are trying to get a directory listing with a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to access the directory through a **URL** when instead you need to **path to the directory**

So rather than doing

```
//This probably equates to "http://localhost/codeigniter/images/directory
$dirname = site_url()."images/users/";
```

You want to do

```
$dirname = FCPATH . "images/users/";
```

The `FCPATH` constant is defined at the bottom of the `index.php` and should be the path to your `index.php` file

Comment: Use: APPPATH for directory to application, and BASEPATH for directory to system.

Comment: my images folder is in the root folder: "mywebsite.com/images/" how do I access that from CI application views without using site_url ?

Comment: it found the images but it's not displaying them. just the box, as if the link is broken. but the images are there.